# Google Map Api v3 polyline and polygon breaking

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have developed a simple google map application with their api in version 3. Since everything worked fine on my machine I sent it to my colleague, who has reported that on his computer polyline breaks and shifts its part in a random manner (as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0SUH.jpg)). Similar thing happens with regions, which also shits a part of its filling along with the outlining.

Code for the polyline is pretty simple:

```
var opts = eval(json);
var options = {
    strokeColor: opts.color,
    strokeOpacity: opts.opacity,
    strokeWeight: opts.weight,
    geodesic: true
}; 
var line = new google.maps.Polyline(options);

line.setPath(google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(opts.points));
line.setMap(map);
```

and I can't really figure out what is the reason for this. This looks like an error in google map rendering. It happens for him every time and in inconsistent areas. The colleague is using IE 9, while I (and other colleague, who is also not experiencing this error) IE 8.

So I'm asking if anyone has encountered a similar problem or has any idea what could be causing it.

EDIT:
I have updated my IE to version 9 and still works fine on my PC, so it is not IE version issue.

EDIT 2:
It is caused by not normal dpi on colleague's system. Higher dpi values cause google maps to render improperly. My research on google gave no useful solutions (other than trivial "change your dpi"). If anyone has any ideas how to fix this, I will be much obliged.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: could you post the exact json string, please?

Comment: values varies depending on situation of course but here is a sample:({color: '#FF0000',weight: 1,opacity: 1.0,points: 'someEncodedPoints',levels: 'someEncodedLevels',zoomFactor: 16, numLevels: 4})

Comment: How does the decoded path look like? I mean after `decodePath(...)`.

Comment: @Jiri: it is an array of google.maps.LatLng objects with coordinates same as provided before encoding, exactly as setPath needs it to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in EDIT2 in question this glitch is caused by non-standard dpi setting. Google's official position on this is to change system dpi to standard, so there is probably no viable solution for now. Hope this will change with time.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.. HAve you found any alternative way of doing it?

Comment: @writeToBhuwan unfortunately I did not, but to be fair, I did not look for any since this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the `json` string is a stringified object like `json = "{...}"`? In this case enclose it in round parantheses:

```
var opts = eval("(" + json + ")");
```

`eval()` evaluates *expressions* and an *expression* cannot start with curly brace.

EDIT: Even better would be

```
var opts = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: json is generated in c# and is like: "({{...}})", so starts with ( and ends with ) so this is not the case, but thank you for your response

Comment: Why the eval() ? as stated it will solve expressions - on purpose ? If just one little expression:  lets say ISO8601 date somewhere 2011-08-23 reduced to 1980 - because it does the calculation ...